# Zxing.net decode returning null on scan windows phone store app

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, zxing

I have following code which is used to capture the stream image from camera.

Following is the code to setup camera, where I initialize it, set maximum resolution, disable flash, rotate the view, set mirroring and start the preview.

```
_mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);

var maxResolution =
    _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.Photo)
        .Aggregate(
            (i1, i2) =>
                (i1 as VideoEncodingProperties).Width > (i2 as VideoEncodingProperties).Width ? i1 : i2);
await _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync(MediaStreamType.Photo, maxResolution);

_mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.AssistantLightEnabled = false;
_mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl.Enabled = false;
_mediaCapture.SetPreviewRotation(VideoRotation.Clockwise90Degrees);
_mediaCapture.SetPreviewMirroring(true);
_mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.PrimaryUse = CaptureUse.Photo;

VideoCapture.Source = _mediaCapture;
await _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
```

After a timer runs, following code is used to capture the photo in a `stream`:

```
var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), stream);

using (stream)
{
    var writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap(1, 1);
    stream.Seek(0);
    await writeableBmp.SetSourceAsync(stream);
    writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap(writeableBmp.PixelWidth, writeableBmp.PixelHeight);
    stream.Seek(0);
    await writeableBmp.SetSourceAsync(stream);
    _result = ScanBitmap(writeableBmp);
}
```

Which passes the writeable bitmap object to the barcode scan function to `Decode`:

```
private Result ScanBitmap(WriteableBitmap writeableBmp)
{
    var barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader
    {
        AutoRotate = true,
        TryInverted = true,
        Options =
        {
            PureBarcode = false,
            TryHarder = true,
            PossibleFormats = new[]
            {
                BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
                BarcodeFormat.EAN_13
            }
        },
    };

    var result = barcodeReader.Decode(writeableBmp);
    return result;
}
```

I have used several options as they can be seen above, but the scan does not succeed. The `Decode` function always returns null. I have also tried the `ResultFound` event of `barcodeReader`, but still the same.

Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried passing it a static image that has a very clear barcode in it?  This is to rule out the crappy camera image.  In my application, I have to focus the image heavily before zxing was able to decode it.

Comment: I tried with a static image and was able to scan perfectly. So what is wrong here with my code, or is there anything I can do to enhance the image to scan?

Comment: Yeah, I think you need to tell the camera to focus on a region of the preview area.  In WP8.0, it was simple as calling `FocusAtPoint` and hooking up the `AutoFocusCompleted` event then decoding the image from there.

Comment: Yes already using `FocusAsync` to adjust focus, but still not working as expected. However if I zoom the barcode image to really big, the scan seems to work most of the time.

Comment: Hmm, maybe this `ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg()` is not enough quality.  Try something with lossless property like PNG or BMP.

Comment: Also try to .Invalidate() the writeable bitmap before decode.

Comment: Tried both things, but no success. Just noticed, It does not even seem to scan QR code.

Comment: Do you know if there is a windows store app vresion of this library? This seems to work pretty fast and is very much accurate:
http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Optical_Reader_Library_for_Windows_Phone_8

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post but I had the same issue and this may save some people some time. For me it was related to focus. On some phones the drivers are at fault according to this link:

> [known issues with Nokia drivers](http://msicc.net/?p=4208) and the new MediaCapture API’s,
>   as [described here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fd02eabc-8ac6-408c-bff9-d540ffd05b2c/mediacapture-with-windows-phone-81?forum=wpdevelop). Microsoft is working with Nokia (or their devices
>   department) to fix this problem. The only solution I got working for
>   an Runtime app is to use manual focus. All other attempts gave me one
>   Exception after the other, be it on cancelling the preview or be it on
>   while previewing itself.

Anyway, that link gives a solution using a slider to control focus!

Comment: In the link I mentioned using a Slider that calls SetFocus, for Barcode scanning it's a better user experience to hide the slider and call SetFocus in a loop before CapturePhotoToStreamAsync. I used a value of 100, and it's assumed the user will in effect "be the Slider". It was important to call SetFocus inside the loop.